# Tag info pages seem to have an empty <title>

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

E.g this one: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Comment: I read that entry as "Haskell is a pure fictional programming language" at first.

Comment: my bad ill sort it tomorrow

Comment: Not just the tag wiki, but all four of the 'new' tag pages, it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this in dev, it should be deployed in the next few hours

Comment: That's better! One Q, I can't see a link back from info/faq/host answers/... tab set to the normal question tab set (newest/featured/...) -- am I missing something?